# Haskell: List all common factors

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

I am learning Haskell and am currently creating a program that finds all common divisors from 3 different Int:s.
I have a working program but the evaluation time is very long on big numbers. I want advice on how to optimize it.

EXAMPLE: `combineDivisors 234944 246744 144456 == [1,2,4,8]`

As said I am very new to this so any help is appreciated.

```
import Data.List

combineDivisors :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
combineDivisors n1 n2 n3 =
    mergeSort list
    where list = getTrips concList
          concList = isDivisor n1 ++ isDivisor n2 ++ isDivisor n3
             
isDivisor n = [x | x <- [1..n], mod n x == 0]

getTriplets :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
getTriplets = map head . filter (\l -> length l > 2) . group . sort


--Merge sort--

split :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
split xs =
   let
     l = length xs `div` 2
   in
    (take l xs, drop l xs)

merge :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
   | y < x = y : merge (x:xs) ys
   | otherwise = x : merge xs (y:ys)

mergeSort :: [Int] -> [Int]
mergeSort [] = []
mergeSort [x] = [x]
mergeSort xs =
   let
     (xs1,xs2) = split xs
   in
    merge (mergeSort xs1) (mergeSort xs2)
```

Comment: Function `isDivisor` has a name that seems to imply it returns a boolean value. Better use `divisorList` perhaps. Efficiency: you might start by decomposing a number into powers of prime numbers. See the [Wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers) on prime numbers maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care too much about memory usage, you can just use `Data.IntSet` and a function to find all factors given a number to do this.

First, let's make a function that returns an `IntSet` of all factors of a number-

```hs
import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet

factors :: Int -> IntSet.IntSet
factors n = IntSet.fromList . f $ 1    -- Convert the list of factors into a set
  where
      -- Actual function that returns the list of factors
      f :: Int -> [Int]
      f i
        -- Exit when i has surpassed square root of n
        | i * i > n = []
        | otherwise = if n `mod` i == 0
            -- n is divisible by i - add i and n / i to the list
            then i : n `div` i : f (i + 1)
            -- n is not divisible by i - continue to the next
            else f (i + 1)
```

Now, once you have the `IntSet` corresponding to each number, you just have to do a [`intersection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Set.html#v:intersection) on them to get the result

```hs
commonFactors :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
commonFactors n1 n2 n3 = IntSet.toList $ IntSet.intersection (factors n3) $ IntSet.intersection (factors n1) $ factors n2
```

That works but is a bit ugly. How about making an `intersections` function that can take multiple `IntSet`s and produce a final intersection result.

```hs
intersections :: [IntSet.IntSet] -> IntSet.IntSet
intersections [] = IntSet.empty
intersections (t:ts) = foldl IntSet.intersection t ts
```

That should fold on a list of `IntSet`s to find the final intersection

Now you can refactor `commonFactors` to-

```hs
commonFactors :: Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
commonFactors n1 n2 n3 = IntSet.toList . intersections $ [factors n1, factors n2, factors n3]
```

Better? I'd think so. How about one last improvement, a general `commonFactors` function for `n` amount of ints

```hs
commonFactors :: [Int] -> [Int]
commonFactors = IntSet.toList . intersections . map factors
```

Note that this is using an `IntSet`, so it is naturally limited to `Int`s. If you want to use `Integer` instead - just replace `IntSet` with a regular `Set Integer`

#### Output

```hs
> commonFactors [234944, 246744, 144456]
[1,2,4,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the standard algorithm where you prime factorize their GCD:

```hs
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

-- infinite list of primes
primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2:3:filter
    (\n -> not $ any
        (\p -> n `mod` p == 0)
        (takeWhile (\p -> p * p <= n) primes))
    [5,7..]

-- prime factorizing a number
primeFactorize :: Integer -> [Integer]
primeFactorize n
    | n <= 1 = []
    -- we search up to the square root to find a prime factor
    -- if we find one then add it to the list, divide and recurse
    | Just p <- find
        (\p -> n `mod` p == 0)
        (takeWhile (\p -> p * p <= n) primes) = p:primeFactorize (n `div` p)
    -- if we don't then the number has to be prime so we're done
    | otherwise = [n]

-- count the number of each element in a list
-- e.g.
-- getCounts [1, 2, 2, 3, 4] == fromList [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
getCounts :: (Ord a) => [a] -> M.Map a Int
getCounts [] = M.empty
getCounts (x:xs) = M.insertWith (const (+1)) x 1 m
    where m = getCounts xs

-- get all possible combinations from a map of counts
-- e.g. getCombos (M.fromList [('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)])
-- == ["","c","cc","b","bc","bcc","a","ac","acc","ab","abc","abcc","aa","aac","aacc","aab","aabc","aabcc"]
getCombos :: M.Map a Int -> [[a]]
getCombos m = allFactors
    where
        list = M.toList m
        factors = fst <$> list
        counts = snd <$> list
        possible = (\n -> [0..n]) <$> counts
        allCounts = sequence possible
        allFactors = (\count -> concat $ zipWith replicate count factors) <$> allCounts

-- get the common factors of a list of numbers
commonFactorsList :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
commonFactorsList [] = []
commonFactorsList l = sort factors
    where
        totalGcd = foldl1 gcd l
        -- then get the combinations them and take their products to get the factor
        factors = map product . getCombos . getCounts . primeFactorize $ totalGcd

-- helper function for 3 numbers
commonFactors3 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
commonFactors3 a b c = commonFactorsList [a, b, c]
```